# Connecting to Db2 from .Net application

Tags: .net

Consider a windows 7 desktop with IBM DB2 10.5 trial version installed.

1. I need to create new tables in the DB2 database and insert data into the tables.
2. I need to connect to this database from Visual Studio in an .Net application.

What is the best approach for achieving this?

Refer: “[IBM Data Server Driver Package](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=swg-idsdpds)”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db2 Command Window (`db2cmd`) can be used to insert data to the database

**Connection String**

"Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = TIMS; Hostname = localhost; Protocol = TCPIP; Port = 50010; Uid = myUserID; Pwd = myPassword";

Refer [No start database manager command was issued error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482339/no-start-database-manager-command-was-issued-error) also