# No start database manager command was issued error

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I have a DB2 expresss in my machine and I am able to query from the database using command window (after following two commands):

```
set DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
db2 connect to tims user
```

Now, when I try to connect to the database from a C# console application, I am getting following errors with different connection strings.

**Attempt 1**

```
 string connectionString = @"Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = TIMS; Hostname = localhost;  CurrentSchema=db2inst1;  ";
```

> SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019

**Attempt 2**

```
string connectionString = @"Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = TIMS;  CurrentSchema=db2inst1;  ";
```

> SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.  SQLSTATE=58031

What should be the correct connection string for this scenario?

**CODE**

```
        string connectionString = @"Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = TIMS; Hostname = localhost;  CurrentSchema=db2inst1;  ";

        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        myConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My DB2 insatnce name is "db2inst1" and it was working fine when I used DB2 command window.

Now I made following settings and it is working fine now. :-)

1. Created a port in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services file   (db2c_db2inst1 50010/tcp)
2. Set the “TCP/IP Service Name” (  = db2c_db2inst1”) for the instance. Verified  using “db2 get dbm cfg”  command
3. Updated the environment variable DB2INSTANCE with the value “db2inst1”
4. Restarted the machine
5. Started the instance

**ConnectionString**

> "Provider = IBMDADB2; Database = TIMS; Hostname = localhost; Protocol = TCPIP; Port = 50010; Uid = myUserID; Pwd = myPassword";

**CODE**

```
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM DBATABC";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                        {
                            string companyCode = reader.GetString(0).ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Note: Try to create DSN for ODBC and use ODBC connection in a sample SSIS package. This will help in resolving OLEDB connection issues also (that are common to both)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have multiple DB2 instances running on your machine?  You can get a list of instances that exist by executing the `db2ilist` command.

If you *have* to execute the `set DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1` statement when you open a DB2 Command Window in order to connect to the `TIMS` database with the `db2 connect to TIMS` command, then you need to ensure that the environment for your C# application is configured the same way.

You can do this in a number of ways:

- by setting the DB2INSTANCE environment variable before starting your application
- Change the default DB2 instance on your machine by using the command `db2set -g DB2INSTDEF=db2inst1`  (** see note below)
- Use a TCPIP connection string (as described by @Bhaarat) so that your application does not depend on the database catalog for the default instance

**Note:** Before changing `DB2INSTDEF` you may want to see what the current value is, by executing the command `db2set -all` and looking for `DB2INSTDEF` in the output.  Also note that changing the default instance may affect other applications that run on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

refer this url http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-ibm-db2/

your connection string should be something like this

```
 Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=urDataBase;Hostname=urServerAddress;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;
Uid=urUsername;Pwd=urPassword;
```

in more you can refer this too
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4870/Connect-to-DB2-from-Microsoft-NET